# Error installing ODL plugins (Argon-SR3 karaf 0.18.3) en ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: apache-karaf

The error when I install all ODL plugins is as follows

**opendaylight-user@root>feature:install old-mdsal-all
Error executing command: No matching features for old-mdsal-all/0**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaDLV.png)

I updated packages, java 17  and it doesn't fix